# How to order Order Date by Order Count SQL?

Tags: sql, oracle

This might be a silly newbie question, but I am trying to figure out how to order something.

How would you construct an SQL statement so that in a table ORDERING with an ORDERDATE attribute I can see how many orders placed on each date?

I know that the following query makes it so it is organized by the date but I want to know how many duplicates for each date in order to find how many orders placed in a day.

```
SELECT *
FROM ORDERING
ORDER BY ORDERDATE DESC;
```

Comment: Could you provide some sample data and expect result?

Answer (score 2):

Count is an aggregate function, so you have to GROUP BY the attribute you want to aggregate.

```
SELECT ORDERDATE,COUNT(*)
FROM ORDERING
GROUP BY ORDERDATE
ORDER BY ORDERDATE DESC;
```

en making questiuons.

Comment: Thank you both for your help. I assumed if I tagged Oracle which is the interface I was using it would be enough.

Comment: Oh...Seems I missed it. It is enough, indeed.

Answer (score 1):

```
SELECT ORDERDATE,COUNT(*)
    FROM ORDERING
GROUP BY ORDERDATE
HAVING COUNT(*)>1
```

Comment: What does Count(*)>1 do? Does it only group by orders with more than one order?

Comment: It will give records which are having duplicates